# What do LT and GT mean?

Tags: haskell

```
GHCi> compare 2 3
LT
GHCi> compare 3 3
EQ
GHCi> compare 4 3
GT
```

I think EQ means equal, but what do LT and GT mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- `compare 2 3 = LT` — 2 is **L**ess **T**han 3
- `compare 3 3 = EQ` — 3 is **EQ**ual to 3
- `compare 4 3 = GT` — 4 is **G**reater **T**han 3

It's unfortunate that the [documentation for `Ordering`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Ordering) does not explicitly spell this out.

Comment: It's quite obvious to native English speakers, but we probably overestimate its obviousness to non-native English speakers.

Answer (score 6):

It's not in haskell only, `GT` and `LT` are very common and well known acronyms respectively for **Greater Than** and **Less Than**. Other common acronyms for comparisons include **GE** and **LE**, i.e. **Greater or Equal** and **Less or Equal**, but they are not part of the Haskell's `Ordering` data constructors. You are right about `EQ` = "equal".

Answer (score 4):

`LT` = less than

`GT` = greater than